# Easy installing matplotlib - missing script easy_install-xrixnr

Tags: installation, matplotlib, easy-install

While trying to install matplotlib, I've received the following error message (see bottom):

```
C:\Users\UserName>easy_install matplotlib
Searching for matplotlib
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/
Reading http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.3/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=278194
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706
Reading https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=80706&package_id=82474
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1/
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/
Best match: matplotlib 1.0.1-r0
Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.0.1/matplotlib-1.0.1_r0-py2.6-win32.egg/download
Processing download
error: Couldn't find a setup script in c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-xrixnr\download
```

Environment: Python 2.6, Win7 64bit
Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [instructions](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html):

1. Install numpy - you can use `easy_install numpy`
2. Install matplotlib from an [installation binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/)
3. You're also invited to install [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/), although it is not mandatory - you can use `easy_install ipyhton`